# Symfony2: Route "login_check" does not exist

Tags: symfony, authentication, routes

I'm pretty new to Symfony, and I'm trying to create a login form with users from a database.

So far I know I have to put my login_check behind a firewall, and not create a controller for it, yet still I get this error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Route "login_check" does not exist.") in EventBundle:Security:login.html.twig at line 11.`

My security.yml:

```
jms_security_extra:
secure_all_services: false
expressions: true

security:
  encoders:
    SocialGeo\EventBundle\Entity\User:
      algorithm: sha512
      encode-as-base64: true
      iterations: 10

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER: ROLE_USER
    ROLE_CITYWORKER: ROLE_DISTRICTWORKER
    ROLE_ADMIN: ROLE_CITYWORKER
    ROLE_SUPERADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH

  providers:
    administrators:
      entity: { class: SocialGeo\EventBundle\Entity\User, property: username }

  firewalls:
    main:
      pattern: /.*
      form_login: 
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login_check
        remember_me: true
      logout:
        path: /logout
        target: /
      security: true
      anonymous: true
```

Routing.yml:

```
EventBundle_login:
  pattern: /login
  defaults: { _controller: EventBundle:Security:login }
  requirements:
    _method: GET|POST

EventBundle_login_check:
  pattern: /login_check

EventBundle_logout:
  pattern: /logout
```

My twig template:

```
{% extends 'EventBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}Login{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% if error %}
<div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="_password" />
    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Does anyone know why I get this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just fixed it.

It worked when I removed the 'EventBundle' prefix from my routing.yml.

Like this:

```
login:
 pattern: /login
 defaults: { _controller: EventBundle:Security:login }
 requirements:
   _method: GET|POST

login_check:
 pattern: /login_check

logout:
 pattern: /logout
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but just so everyone is aware what happened here, changing the route names, as this person has done works. However, the original route names would have worked too.

Instead of this:

```
<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
```

It should have been this:

```
<form action="{{ path('EventBundle_login_check') }}" method="post">
```

The twig path function needs the route name to generate the correct URL.